# for next loop syntax

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```
Sub test()
' I have two spreadsheets: Managers and Reports
' Managers is a list of managers
' Report has all the managers and all the people that report to them
' I want to use the Managers spreadsheet as a source to filter the report spreadsheet for all the people that report to that manager
' and them copy the filtered data to a tab in the reports spreadsheet.
' There is a tab in the reports spreadsheet that is named after the manager
' So John Doe is on the list of managers on the manager sheet
' I want to filter the report spreadsheet for John Doe and then copy the filtered data to a tab on the reports spreadsheet named John Doe
' The reports spreadsheet already has a tab named John Doe

' so i think i need to define both spreadsheets
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbReport As Workbook

'and define the tabs in each workbook
Dim wsManagers As Worksheet
Dim wsReport As Worksheet

'and define the range in the source spreadsheet that has the names
Dim n As Range
' n = wbSource wsManagers ' I don't know the syntax here

'  So I'm thinking I need a for next loop to go through the list of managers
' filter the report spreadsheet
' copy that filtered data to the appropriate tab in the report spreadsheet

n = 1
For n = 1 To 127
    'Filter report spreadsheet
    ' copy filtered data to correct tab
Next n

End Sub
```

This is a lot and Ive spent hours trying to make something work
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you post some sample data (mgrs/reports) and your existing code, it will help. Even if it's just structured pseudo-code. It looks like you may have tried pasting in code - use triple backtick wrappers in the post editor. If your question is really just "how do I do a for loop in VBA", you might only need this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Comment: So, you haven't done anything yet to access the data in the spreadsheets?  Surely that must be step one.  If you can just print the names of the managers, you'd be a long ways towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a minimal approach of the task. Use only one workbook with the sheets named `Managers` and `Report`. Before start the code check that there are no sheets named as the managers names.

```
Sub filter_managers()

Dim wsManagers As Worksheet, wsReport As Worksheet
Set wsManagers = Worksheets("Managers")
Set wsReport = Worksheets("Report")

With wsManagers
  Set manager_range = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
End With
For i = 1 To manager_range.Rows.Count
  Set man_sheet = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
  man_name = wsManagers.Cells(i, 1)
  wsReport.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, man_name
  wsReport.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy man_sheet.Range("A1")
  'if you don't want the names of the manager in the first column activate the next line
  'man_sheet.Columns(1).Delete
  man_sheet.Name = man_name
  wsReport.ShowAllData
Next i
wsReport.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @black cat, this looks good but I have some questions.  I could use just one spreadsheet but how would that work when filtering the sheet?  Seems like I need a list of managers that has only one instance of the managers' names. like the list in the Managers' spreadsheet.